# How to update certain parts of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, checkbox

I'm looking to create a report with similar that has a checkbox next to each row. Each row has some fields that are editable (such as comments). What I'd like is to give the user the ability to check off which rows he/she would like to update by selecting the checkbox next to that row. Then I'd have a save button at the bottom of the form that only updates the rows that have a check box active next to it.

I'm pretty new to rails and web programming in general so any advice/direction you might be able to give me should prove helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A popular way to achieve this is to :

1- All your checkboxes should share the same name.

2- All your checkboxes' values should be the ID of the row/object

3- When you POST the form, only the checked checkboxes are in the POST data. Retrieve those IDS and only update these objects.

For example, your checkbox should be something like :

```
<%= check_box_tag "row_ids[]", row.id, false, :id => "row_#{row.id}" %>
```

Then, in your controller :

```
Row.find(params[:row_ids]).each do |row|
  # do whatever you want
end
```

Comment: does Row in my controller here have to be a model? or do you mean to use the model behind my report?

Comment: also...this is a piece that i'm particularly unclear on - where does the "Row.find" part go in my controller? i currently only have initialize() and show() in my controller. Do i need a different method that handles the post?

Comment: Row is your model. And the piece of code goes into a controller action.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this, but it adds more work for the user: they have to check off multiple checkboxes before hitting Update. It be nicer if they just hit Update and it worked.

The basic idea is you want the user to just click Update and your code only updates records that changed.

What you can do is store (in a hidden field tag) the ID of each row's record. Then when you update, you loop through all rows and you grab (based on the ID stored in the hidden field) the record from the database. Let's say only Comments were editable. Then you can check to see if the comments have actually been changed (like with a simple string comparison) and if they have, update it. If more things are editable, then you can check them too before deciding if you need to update or not.

That is a high level description, but let me know if you want some more implementation details.